# Vue ctrl+s event listener not firing

Tags: vue.js

My application dialog should respond to "Ctrl+S" for a save function and cancel the default browser Save event.

```
<div
  @keyup.83="doSave"
  @keyup.ctrl.83="doSave"
  @keyup.alt.83="doSave"
  tabindex="0">
```

The doSave event is fired on pressing 's' (and `alt+s`) but not on `ctrl+s`.

Why is `ctrl+s` not fired?

BONUS QUESTION: Is there a way to `preventDefault` without coding it? Somehow it should be possible adding `.once` but the docs are vague.

https://codepen.io/cawoodm/pen/qvgxPL

Comment: When i press ctrl+s doSave fires 2 times. one for ctrl+s , and 's' keyup. I think tabindex is the issue. in chrome i  have to click the element to get focus. after that only... keyup events working.

Comment: Same behavior as mentioned by @dagalti

Comment: manually focus element on mounted. `mounted(){
this.$el.focus()
},`  Then press keys.  Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaqQaK

Comment: Moreover, if you add `exact` modifier then it will click only once. but you need to write for both: https://codepen.io/varit05/pen/xBMYNe?editors=1111

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several questions packed into your question, so I am going to answer them one by one:

## Why is ctrl+s not fired?

Several reasons. You are using the `keyup` event, while the browser starts to save the page on a keydown event. Your keyup event is thus never fired.

For any event to be registered on your div, your div **must** have focus, because otherwise the event will not originate from that element, but instead from (presumably) the body.

## Is there a way to preventDefault without coding it?

Yes. Add the `prevent` modifier to your event. In the same way, you can use `once` to unregister an event after it has triggered once, `stop` to use `stopPropagation()` and `passive` to explicitly not stop propagation. You would use something like: `@keydown.ctrl.83.prevent="saveMe"`.

## How do I get this working?

If you are fine with the user having to focus the element before being able to save, and otherwise getting the default behaviour, use the following:

```
<div
  id="app"
  tabindex="0"
  @keydown.ctrl.83.prevent.stop="saveInsideComponent"
>
  <!-- -->
</div>
```

Otherwise, this is one of the few moments where registering your own event listener is useful. Just make sure to remove it before your component is destroyed, or you will have a rogue event listener throwing errors on other components + a memory leak to deal with.

```
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.doSave);
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.doSave);
  },

  methods: {
    doSave(e) {
      if (!(e.keyCode === 83 && e.ctrlKey)) {
        return;
      }

      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("saving from DOM!");
    },
  }
```

[image: Edit Vue + Vuex + VueRouter template]

Comment: Excellent answer though the focus stuff is off point: my div is focussable and the other keyup events are indeed fired. Thanks muchly!

Answer (score 7):

@Sumurai8's answer is great but I would add support for apple devices by checking if `e.metaKey` is == true. The code then looks like this:

```js
      mounted() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.doSave);
      },
    
      beforeDestroy() {
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.doSave);
      },
    
      methods: {
        doSave(e) {
          if (!(e.keyCode === 83 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey))) {
            return;
          }
    
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log("saving from DOM!");
        },
      }
```